# r find a row with filter then replace single cell value

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have data in the following format:

```
        col1   col2  col3  col4
row1     xx    100    ABC
row2     xx    10     ABC
row3     xx    100    BYZ
```

And need to find a specific value by multiple conditions and multiply it. I wish to take the 10 value in col2 and row2 and multiply it by 100.

The data frame is too large and will change with each refresh so the problematic value must be found by searching for conditions.

The code I have used to find our desired value is:

```
dplyr::filter(data, col3 == 'ABC' & col1 == 'xx')[2]
```

But attempting to re-assign this like so:

```
dplyr::filter(data, col3 == 'ABC' & col1 == 'xx)[2]
<- dplyr::filter(data, col3 == 'ABC' & col1 == 'xx')[2]
 * 100
```

Is met with a new error that filter()<- is not a subset function of dplyr.

I tried reverting back to an earlier version of dplyr without improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `ifelse` to change the values in `col2` for specific conditions.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(col2 = ifelse(col3 == 'ABC' & col1 == 'xx', col2 * 100, col2))
```

Or keeping it in base :

```
transform(df, col2 = ifelse(col3 == 'ABC' & col1 == 'xx', col2 * 100, col2))
```

Also there is no `filter<-` function defined so you can't use it directly.